# Sailing from the Wash, UK to France during World War II.

Tags: sailing, history

Would it have been possible to sail a small boat from [The Wash, Norfolk, UK](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/The+Wash+National+Nature+Reserve/@52.9920189,0.0938593,10z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0xbb9ec420d4add213!8m2!3d52.8235124!4d0.2835846?shorturl=1) to Dunkirk in WWII? Could it be done in one go? If not, where would you stop en route?

[image]

Comment: You'll also have to define small.

Comment: @Suewriter - if you can edit your question to make it more specific it may be able to be reopened, however the simple answer as it stands is: Yes. It has always been possible to sail small boats vast distances. The Wash to Dunkirk is not far. So "is it possible" is not a good question here. What are you trying to ask?

Comment: @Olin - while we definitely expect old hands to understand the rules, lets be a bit more welcoming to new folks. More than happy to put on hold while a question is fixed, but lets help them understand what that means. Your close reason is fine but calling someone arrogant because they don't know our rules is not helpful.

Comment: The problem would not be sailing. The problem would be avoiding being fired upon or captured and executed as a spy. You didn't just go sailing across the English Channel during WWII.

Comment: Sometime ago I asked about sailing from the Wash to Dunkirk in World War II. I need to know because I am a novelist and need a character to do that. Someone posted some really helpful maps and information but I am afraid I can’t quite find my way around this site to see the name of the person who did. I would love to ask more.

Comment: Someone else also asked bout the size of the boat. I am not a sailor so don’t know. What sort of craft could be sailed single handed from the Wash to Dunkirk. Which port or harbour would you need to stop in on the way? What sort of conditions would you need? I am a novice to these things and would appreciate more help. The maps below were useful. Thank you

Answer (score 9):

> Would it have been possible to sail a small boat from The Wash,
>   Norfolk, UK to Dunkirk in WWII?

During the evacuation of Dunkirk the authorities called on all available civilian boats to aid in the evacuation. These were called ["The little ships of Dunkirk"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ships_of_Dunkirk).

These ships gathered at Ramsgate before moving with the larger ships to Dunkirk. These boats we're mostly used as ferries to the larger boats. The distance from the Wash to Ramsgate is about 175 miles.

[image]

then another 45 miles to Dunkirk

[image]

Now you don't state how big this small boat is. But a reasonably sized boat should be able to make this journey in several hours. It's certainly less than a days sailing.

Two of the lifeboats in the list of ships stand out in relation to this question:

- Herbert Sturmey (ON 664) from [Aldeburgh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aldeburgh_Lifeboat_Station)
- Lucy Lavers (ON 832) from [Cadgwith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadgwith#Lifeboats)

Though not quite as far north **Aldeburgh** isn't that far further south of the Wash:

[image]

Cadwith is much further away than the wash though in an Easterly direction:

[image]
[image]

Roughly a 319 miles, nearly twice the distance of The Wash

My Grandad was involved in Dunkirk and sailed a boat (he was a lifeboatman) from Rhyl in North Wales to Dunkirk at around the same time. This journey is much longer than the one you described:

[image]

A journey of about 641 miles! The evacuation of Dunkirk lasted just over a week. So it's very much possible.

Comment: One of the "little ships" is the Tamzine, its a very small vessel and a well known one both by sailors and historians. Its considered the smallest of the ones in the evacuation.

Comment: As per Erik's comment, the Tamzine was a 15 footer. See http://www.iwm.org.uk/collections/item/object/30004026